Variation of $g(t)$
It has been many days since I had this question: Despite being able to find out $g(r)$ I am unable to find out $g(t)$.
Where $g$ = gravitational acceleration, $r =$ distance apart.
When trying to understand this, in my mind I am thinking of this case: an object is released from rest at a comparable distance from earth, under only the Earth's gravity.
Is $g$ not a function of $t$? But it should be (my notion) so how does $g$ vary with $t$? Question from classical gravitation.
g(r) is a formula we learn at the beginning. But in order to find g(t) I need r(t), which is what? (At least in some cases r varies with t, even though g in the formula of r(t) as 2nd equation keeps changing? Or not?)

I do not know calculus. So if you give answers using that, it will be of great help when I refer to it in future. But currently not...

$r(t)$ is… complicated. Don’t go there.

Is g not a function of t? The acceleration of a falling object increases as it falls, but it’s not particularly useful to think about it as a function of time.

What is very simple is the differential equation: $\ddot r=-GM/r^2$. The function $t(r)$ is reasonably simple.

@Ghoster Could you explain why we couldn't just use $s=ut+\frac{1}{2}at^2$ to find the distance from earth as a function of time?

@sticky That equation is used when a is constant. It's not valid when the acceleration changes with distance.

@Swls Sorry, but calculus was basically invented to tackle problems like this. As Ghoster says, finding time as a function of position isn't too hard, but finding position as a function of time is really tricky. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_equation

I think you are struggling with the differences between implicit and explicit time dependence, which was well explained here.
It is true that, since $r=r(t)$ and generally $g=g(r)$, we think about $g$ varying on time, but this variation is implicit. Explicitly, we could say that $g\neq g(t)$ and
$$
{\partial g\over \partial t} = 0.
$$
The total time derivative, on the other hand, would be not zero, since
$$
{dg\over dt} = {dr\over dt}{dg\over dr}
$$
And the two quantities on the r.h.s. are generally not zero. We have
$$
g(r) = {GM\over r^2} \rightarrow {dg\over dr} = {-2GM\over r^3} = -\frac 2r g(r)
$$
So we can write
$$
{dg\over dt} = -\frac 2r {dr\over dt} g(r)
$$
There is no scape but to calculate $r(t)$ explicitly and get the derivative, which people already explained in the comments that it is a hard task. What you can do is to consider some approximations for $r(t)$, but I'm not sure how much insightful it can be, since at the end you only have an implicit time dependence. In fact, the expression above will only give you $g(r(t))$ again, and it could only be thought as a explicit function of time if we substitute $r$ by $r(t)$ in the expression of $g$ and write $g(t) \equiv g(r(t))$.

Consider for example that for some reason, a body not following a Keplerian orbit have constant negative radial velocity ${dr\over dt} = - C$ for $C>0$ (it is going to the center of earth). Then $r(t) = r_0 - Ct$ and we have
$$
{dg\over dt} = {2C\over r_0 - Ct} g \rightarrow \ln g = -2\ln(r_0-Ct) + K\rightarrow g(t) = {K\over (r_0 -Ct)^2}
$$
Which is the same result we get by inserting $r(t)$ directly in the expression of $g(r)$ and setting the constant $K=GM$.
